# Should I Change My DNS Forwarders?

Tags: domain-name-system

I am currently hosted with NetRegistry.com.au and I'm pointing my domain's namesever to the NetRegistry DNS servers, as forwarders. The current DNS lookup time is 70ms Sydney to Sydney (I'm actually down the block from the datacenter).

Is this a high DNS lookup time? Are there faster DNS providers?

May not seem like a lot, but for me every ms counts.

Answer (score 2):

70ms is a very acceptable query time for DNS. About the only time I see a response come much faster than that is when issue a query to the DNS server on my LAN for which that server is authoritative.

Answer (score -2):

I use afraid.org and it's really great. Free account gets you 25 records for each domain. Comes with web forward too, make cname, mx, and just about any other type of record. Give it a try, and if you don't like it, you didn't pay a cent.

Comment: They're in LAX. The OPs query time is only going to increase if he switches to afraid.org due to the trans-oceanic hop(s).

Comment: For a time, I pointed my name server to the actual root nameservers that were near my area. Not sure if thats a good idea though. You could (wait, resolving dns or dns host?) Point to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google) or the opendns ones. The ip for opendns servers are the 208.xxx.xxx.xxx ones on this site: http://u4ik.us/ip where it says the 208 ones.

Comment: But yes, 70ms is great, your mouse clicks around 70ms. That's pretty fast for me.

Comment: From Australia, the Google DNS is fairly poor. Really, there's not much you can improve over 70ms, and a free (and therefor usually overloaded) DNS service on the opposite side of the world, and then switching to a slow DNS service (in Australia at least)... isn't going to help.

Comment: Understood. And once your system caches the dns records anyways it will be near-instant.

Answer (score -2):

Try **[CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com)** - in my experience, they have the best free DNS system, with unlimited domains and unlimited records per domain, and their speeds are really good. I host all my sites through CloudFlare DNS, some with their "proxy" feature (which they say accelerates sites, but I'm not sure if this is accurate), some without.